# Why don't I get concurrent execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Consider the following minimal program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def mp_test():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('mp_test')

print('start')
p = Process(target=mp_test)
p.run()
print('end')
```

According to my understanding of the [documentation for the `multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing), this code should execute `mp_test()` in a separate process, which means that it should execute in parallel with the main process. Therefore, I expect the following output:

```
start
end
mp_test
```

However, the actual output I get is this:

```
start
mp_test
end
```

Why is this? What changes do I need to make to get the result I'm expecting?

Comment: `p.run()` is a blocking call

Comment: try using
"import os
print 'process id:', os.getpid()"
to see if you are really getting 2 threads, and if so, check for blocking calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> In multiprocessing, processes are spawned by creating a Process object and then calling its start() method.

So it seems you should call `p.start()`, which will in turn call `p.run()` in a separate thread, which should give the result you want.

Calling `p.run()` directly skips the whole multi-threaded bit.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I failed to glean that from the documentation.

Comment: Wait. You don't need both p.start() and p.run() do you? Just p.start() I thought. Also, since it will run in a different process, you may not see the output. If you want to run in as a thread, then `from multiprocessing.dummy import Process` will run it as a separate thread. Then you should see the output since it should share the same stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Try `p.start()` instead of `p.run()`.